# Textbox value remains empty in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a couple of update panels on my page as follows:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
  </Triggers>
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    ...some more basic controls here...
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I hit submit in UpdatePanel1, the value in the textbox is lost. I'm not sure if this is due to having two update panels on the same page or something else.

UpdatePanel2 is where I'm trying to move the textbox value. But for the sake of testing the string, I've removed all my code and simply added a message box on my click event for Button1 to check if the string is being passed. Seems it is an empty string each time.

I've tried setting `ChildrenAsTriggers` to both true and false, removed the triggers section, set the update panel's `enableviewstate` property to true, tried toggling between update modes, but nothing seems to be working.

This probably might be a duplicate, but I've browsed through the posts related to this on here and on Google, but still haven't found any solutions.

Any ideas?

Comment: this code works fine for me. how do you check the value of TextBox1? and show your control/page settings.

Comment: for the moment, I'm just testing using `msgbox(textbox1.text)` to test it. in the previous version of this site (in asp.net 4.0), it works fine. now that i'm doing an upgrade of this code to 4.5, i've run into this problem...

Comment: put something like var test = TextBox1.Text; in the start of your Page_Load event of this control and debug it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, BurundukXP. I should have pointed out that one of my update panels was in a jQuery UI dialog, which made the dialog form outside my form - hence no value being captured on form submit. Hopefully the answer below will help save time for others who run into a similar situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I was using jQuery UI dialog for one of my update panels, which was appending the dialog to the end of the body (outside the form tags). I added the following line to my dialog's script:

```
dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
```

...and it did the trick!